# Results extraction from website

Tags: excel, html-table, html-tableextract, vba

I was trying to extract results from similar table:

https://data.fei.org/Result/ResultList.aspx?p=D6E828828E450E2880525ABCEE800008C1D381967CBAF718D9DE41BEBA3B9F06

I have applied following code but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what table elements should be used?:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim CompetitionLink As String
CompetitionLink = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("B2")
IE.Navigate CompetitionLink
IE.Visible = True

Rank = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("grid sc")(0).Rows(1).Cells(2).innerText

Debug.Print Rank

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to wait for the page to load & "grid sc" is not a TagName.

Comment: *grid sc* is **not** an html tag name; probably a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that code

```html
    Sub Test()
        Dim ie              As New InternetExplorer
        Dim competitionLink As String
        Dim rank            As String

        competitionLink = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("B2")

        With ie
            .Visible = True
            .navigate competitionLink
            Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4

            rank = .document.getElementsByClassName("grid sc")(0).Rows(1).Cells(2).innerText
            Debug.Print rank
        End With
    End Sub
```

** You can also grab all the table data .. Have a look at this link
[Scrape HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850470/scrape-a-html-table-using-excel-vba)